# Products assigned to category root issue

Tags: cataloginventory

So I'm trying to solve a small issue that I noticed in my category setup.

To preface, I'm running a multi-domain install with 2 separate stores. For example purposes, i'll refer to their root categories as domain1 & domain2.

So for domain1, it says there's 0 items assigned to the root. However, when I look at domain2, it says there's 599 items assigned to the root, but when I click on Category Products, it's empty.

In regards to the 599, if I add up the items in the 1st level of categories, they add up to 599. However, if I do the same for domain1, they don't add up to 117, in fact they add up to 865.

Does this seem normal? Also, could having too many products assigned to the root affect pageload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this it typically normal and wasn't the issue behind my pageload.